# Trying to Display "Name" attribute from an Enum in a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to retrieve the `[Display]` text below for whichever enum is saved in the database (i.e., if None, then corresponding is "No thanks.") without having to code an `@if` block in my view. I guess it's not possible, but thought I would ask.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "No thanks.")]
    None,
    [Display(Name = "Yes, send me your 100 Packet.")]
    100Packet,
    [Display(Name = "Yes, send me your 200 Packet.")]
    200Packet
}
```

Right now, the only solution I have is to do this in my view:

```
@Model.MyEnumRadioButton // displays saved item in DB (i.e., "100Packet")

@if (Model.MyEnumRadioButton == MyEnum.None)
{
    <text>No thanks.</text>
}
....
```

and repeat that for each item in the `enum`. For this small example it's no big deal, but I have a lot of different `enum`'s, some with up to 10 choices.

For example, is there something I can do with the `@Model.MyEnumRadioButton` to make it display the text?

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working solution for Asp.NetMVC 5 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75884887/7873901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple answer to my problem:

[MVC.net get enum display name in view without having to refer to enum type in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328972/mvc-net-get-enum-display-name-in-view-without-having-to-refer-to-enum-type-in-vi)

All I have to do is `@MyEnum.100Packet.DisplayName()`

Answer (score 1):

See this post, he is using a description attribute to achieve what you are after I believe:

[How do I have an enum bound combobox with custom string formatting for enum values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796607/how-do-i-override-tostring-in-c-sharp-enums)

Comment: I think he's trying to display those values when the combo-box is generated. In my scenario I can do that no problem. What I am after is a view that is calling up what has been saved in the database. The `enum` value is stored in the DB, and I want to populate my view with the text stored in the attribute, not the `enum`.

Comment: I thought something like `MyEnum.100Packet.ToString();` might work in the view. Something to shortcut having to do an `@if` statement and then writing out `<text>Yes, send me your 100 packet</text>` inside the `@if{}` block.

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem with the link.  He was trying to use it in a combobox and failing, but I think what he was doing would work for you.  You have a view, bound to a model.  On that model, you have a property that stores a value that matches one of the values in the enum.  In that case, using the example from that link, you should just be able to do: `GetDescription<MyEnum>(Model.PropertyThatStoresTheEnumValue);`

Comment: Not that it was a bad example, just overly complex for my scenario (which I admit I didn't explain well). My answer contains quicker solution.