# MVC5: Enum radio button with label as displayname

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

I have these enums

```
public enum QuestionStart
{
    [Display(Name="Repeat till common match is found")]
    RepeatTillCommonIsFound,

    [Display(Name="Repeat once")]
    RepeatOnce,    

    [Display(Name="No repeat")]
    NoRepeat

}

public enum QuestionEnd
{
    [Display(Name="Cancel Invitation")]
    CancelInvitation,

    [Display(Name="Plan with participants on first available common date")]
    FirstAvailableCommon,

    [Display(Name="Plan with participants on my first available common date")]
    YourFirstAvailableCommon
}
```

and I have a helper class to show all the radiobutton for each field in enum

```
@model Enum
@foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()))
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m, value)
    @Html.Label(value.ToString())
    <br/>
}
```

Right now the label is set to the value name and not the display name i have given for values.

For example for:

```
[Display(Name="Cancel Invitation")]
CancelInvitation
```

I get radio button with `CancelInvitation` next to it.

How can I make it display the Display name(`Cancel Invitation`) i have given to it?

Comment: @Biploav13, try this solution and let me know the result - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328972/mvc-net-get-enum-display-name-in-view-without-having-to-refer-to-enum-type-in-vi

Comment: Is the code meant for MVC5 ?

Comment: Where should i implement that function? my view uses Html.EditorFor and I have helper class to show radiobuttons.

Comment: I changed the tag to be more version-specific: MVC4 doesn't seem to handle well feeding a `dynamic` to `RadioButtonFor`

Comment: I think i updated to mvc 5.1 but how do i check?

Comment: Check the packages.config for MVC version.

Comment: I need radio buttons, not dropdownlist :(

Comment: Oh yea, I got you. Sorry for side tracking. I am going to delete my comments.

Comment: Give me some time, I will give you working solution

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here goes the solution -

[Credit goes to this extraordinary gentleman - ThumNet, who wrote RadioButtonList for Enum as an extension](https://gist.github.com/ThumNet/1010654)

**Step 1 -** Create **RadioButtonListEnum.cshtml** file with below code (code from above reference) in **Views/Shared/EditorTemplates** directory (if not exist, then create that directory) -

```
@model Enum

@{
     // Looks for a [Display(Name="Some Name")] or a [Display(Name="Some Name", ResourceType=typeof(ResourceFile)] Attribute on your enum
    Func<Enum, string> getDescription = en =>
    {
        Type type = en.GetType();
        System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {

            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute),
                                                            false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
        }

        return en.ToString();
    };
    var listItems = Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()).OfType<Enum>().Select(e =>
    new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = getDescription(e),
        Value = e.ToString(),
        Selected = e.Equals(Model)
    });
    string prefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    int index = 0;
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Empty;

    foreach (var li in listItems)
    {
        string fieldName = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}_{1}", prefix, index++);
        <div class="editor-radio">
        @Html.RadioButton(prefix, li.Value, li.Selected, new { @id = fieldName }) 
        @Html.Label(fieldName, li.Text)    
        </div>
    }
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix;
}
```

Then have your enum -

```
public enum QuestionEnd
{
    [Display(Name = "Cancel Invitation")]
    CancelInvitation,

    [Display(Name = "Plan with participants on first available common date")]
    FirstAvailableCommon,

    [Display(Name = "Plan with participants on my first available common date")]
    YourFirstAvailableCommon
}
```

**Step 2 -** Create Model -

```
public class RadioEnumModel
{
    public QuestionEnd qEnd { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 3 -** Create Controller Action -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        RadioEnumModel m = new RadioEnumModel();
        return View(m);
    }
```

**Step 4 -** Create View -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.RadioEnumModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.qEnd, "RadioButtonListEnum")
```

Then the output would be -

[image]

Comment: seems to work. Thanks!!! Would be nice if there was inbuilt helper for these situations too, maybe in future version of MVC. But nevertheless votes up and i'll accept the answer!

Comment: 1+ for your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

I found some of these answers confusing, this is how I ended up achieving the result. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Shove this in an extension methods file:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name != null)
    {
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
        if (field != null)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute attr =
                   Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                     typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
            if (attr != null)
            {
                return attr.Description;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Make sure you add a property that is the same type as your enum to your actual Model so that the radio button selection binds.

Create an editor template for your particular enum. Then in your view reference it like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyEnumTypePropertyName)
```

Then add the following to your EditorTemplate:

```
@using MyProject.ExtensionMethods;
@model MyProject.Models.Enums.MyEnumType

    @foreach (MyEnumType value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumType)))
    {
        <div>
            @Html.Label(value.GetDescription())
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m, value)
        </div>
    }
```

**Remember** - If you don't select a radio button for whatever reason, the default value for your enum property when posted will always be the first in the pack (i.e. zero), not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following overload method.

```
@Html.Label(value.ToString(),"Cancel Invitation")
```

This will render the label with specified labeltext provided as second parameter in above call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses an extension method and an editor template to create a radio group with a localized name from the display attribute.

**Extension Method**

```
public static string DisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
{
    var enumType = enumValue.GetType();
    var memberInfo = enumType.GetMember(enumValue.ToString()).First();

    if (memberInfo == null || !memberInfo.CustomAttributes.Any()) return enumValue.ToString();

    var displayAttribute = memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();

    if (displayAttribute == null) return enumValue.ToString();

    if (displayAttribute.ResourceType != null && displayAttribute.Name != null)
    {
        var manager = new ResourceManager(displayAttribute.ResourceType);
        return manager.GetString(displayAttribute.Name);
    }

    return displayAttribute.Name ?? enumValue.ToString();
}
```

**Example**

```
public enum IndexGroupBy 
{
    [Display(Name = "By Alpha")]
    ByAlpha,
    [Display(Name = "By Type")]
    ByType
}
```

And here is its usage:

```
@IndexGroupBy.ByAlpha.DisplayName()
```

**Editor Template**

Here is an editor template that can be used with the extension method above:

```
@model Enum

@{    
    var listItems = Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()).OfType<Enum>().Select(e =>
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = e.DisplayName(),
            Value = e.ToString(),
            Selected = e.Equals(Model)
        });
    var prefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    var index = 0;
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Empty;

    foreach (var li in listItems)
    {
        var fieldName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}_{1}", prefix, index++);
        <div class="editor-radio">
            @Html.RadioButton(prefix, li.Value, li.Selected, new {@id = fieldName})
            @Html.Label(fieldName, li.Text)
        </div>
    }
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix;
}
```

And here is an example usage:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.YourEnumMember, "Enum_RadioButtonList")
```