# Radio Button For multiple bools

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say I have the following properties in my model that I want to be mutually exclusive:

```
public bool PrintWeek1 {get; set;}
public bool PrintWeek2 {get; set;}
public bool PrintWeek3 {get; set;}
```

Is it possible to render these as a set of radio buttons or do I need to change them to an enum?

If I use `@Html.RadioButtonFor` it renders name as the name of the property so they aren't grouped correctly.

Comment: you can give your own name - `new { @Name= "grp" }`, so that they will be grouped together.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3122130/3664659

Comment: A single enum property (with 3 values and 3 corresponding radio buttons) would make more sense

Comment: @ramiramilu ah i was trying with `new {@name = "grp"}` which wasn't overwriting the name MVC was rendering. I'll check now if they post back correctly..

Comment: Actually it works for mutually exclusiveness, But changing the name would actually create problems in `posting` the model. How are you actually posting the data back to server? Instead I would suggest you to use `RadioButtonListFor` like shown here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679249/mvc5-enum-radio-button-with-label-as-displayname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here comes a quick solution, let you have following properties in Model -

```
public bool PrintWeek1 { get; set; }
public bool PrintWeek2 { get; set; }
public bool PrintWeek3 { get; set; }
public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
```

Then your HTML should be like this -

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.PrintWeek1, "PrintWeek1", new { @Name = "SelectedValue" }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.PrintWeek2, "PrintWeek2", new { @Name = "SelectedValue" }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.PrintWeek3, "PrintWeek3", new { @Name = "SelectedValue" })
```

Then when you submit the form, you will get the selected value in `SelectedValue` property.

**EDIT**
To Address @StephenMuecke point, created the below solution -

Create a `enum` -

```
public enum PrintWeekType
{
    PrintWeek1, PrintWeek2, PrintWeek3
}
```

Then have a model property (instead of individual properties, have single emum property) -

```
public PrintWeekType SelectedValue { get; set; }
```

HTML should be like below -

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedValue, PrintWeekType.PrintWeek1) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedValue, PrintWeekType.PrintWeek2) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedValue, PrintWeekType.PrintWeek3)
```

Using above sample, one can pre-select a radiobutton, at the same time we can post the selected value in `SelectedValue` property.

Comment: This wont work and give 2 way model binding. When the view is first rendered, no radio buttons will ever be selected, irrespective of the value of the `boolean` properties

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are right, updated my answer with more precise solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I abandoned the bools and just ended up using a list - this seemed to be the quickest and easiest way to do it.

Where I initialize my model:

```
   public PrintViewModel()
        {
            this.PrintTypes = new List<string>() { "Print Week 1", "Print Week 2", "Print Week 3" };
        }

    public List<string> PrintTypes { get; set; }
    public string SelectedPrintType { get; set; }
```

In my view (I wanted the first option selected by default):

```
   @for(int i = 0; i < Model.PrintTypes.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(i == 0 ? Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedPrintType, Model.PrintTypes[i], new {@checked = "checked"}) : @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedPrintType, Model.PrintTypes[i]))
                    &nbsp;
                    <label for="@Model.PrintTypes[i]">@Model.PrintTypes[i]</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```